# Let's get critical: Feb 2015 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

We all love [Writers Stack Exchange](http://writers.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://writers.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. 
Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Final Results

- [Should embedded figures/images be placed before or after they are referred to in text?](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/15807/should-embedded-figures-images-be-placed-before-or-after-they-are-referred-to-in)

**Net Score: 3** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Unofficial Fan Fictions - How can I Secure Them?](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/15919/unofficial-fan-fictions-how-can-i-secure-them)

**Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Show don't tell advice](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/15929/show-dont-tell-advice)

**Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 0, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [How does one get Fanfiction "Published"?](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/14761/how-does-one-get-fanfiction-published)

**Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [Editing: Those darn comma splices](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/15847/editing-those-darn-comma-splices)

**Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [How do I get publishers and agents to read my full book?](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/15897/how-do-i-get-publishers-and-agents-to-read-my-full-book)

**Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- ["That's when" vs "That was when."](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/15934/thats-when-vs-that-was-when)

**Net Score: -1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [How can I trust that the proofreader and designer of a book will not plagiarize our work?](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/14712/how-can-i-trust-that-the-proofreader-and-designer-of-a-book-will-not-plagiarize)

**Net Score: -1** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [Is there a database of plots that have not been "processed"/used yet?](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/14783/is-there-a-database-of-plots-that-have-not-been-processed-used-yet)

**Net Score: -3** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 3)

---

- [What are my legal rights if somebody writes a book about me without my consent?](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/14780/what-are-my-legal-rights-if-somebody-writes-a-book-about-me-without-my-consent)

**Net Score: -4** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 0, Needs Improvement: 4)

---